# React deployed app works good on web and simulated phone but not actual mobile

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I have a React made website which I will show code for with a minimal example. Everything works fine on the computer, both regular 24" screen and simulated iPhone and Android (both Chrome and Firefox). The problem is that it looks different on my phones (both iOS and Android). Can somebody explain why?

The `index.html` is the basic default for React and starts with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
```

The `.css` file is not used for the minimal example

[Desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZGAB.png)

[Responsive mobile on computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdWNr.png)

[Faulty mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSPmx.png) - **This is the problem!**

**The App.cs file code is:**

```
function App() {

    return (
        <>
            <div className="jumbotron text-center">
                <div className="container">
                    <h1>Mango padel</h1>
                    <p>En community för oss som älskar padel!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Mango</a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li className="active"><a href="#">Medlemmar</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Padelnytt</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Turneringar</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Padelresa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Matchi</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Webshop</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Om oss</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
    
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-12">
                        <h2>Medlemmar</h2>
                        <MemberTable/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div className="jumbotron text-center jumbotron-bottom">
                <div className="container">
                    <h1>Under konstruktion...</h1>
                    <p>Just nu inte anpassad för mobilvy!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
    
}
```

I've tried a lot of changes in my HTML and CSS code.

Comment: Don't you have the desktop mode turned on?

Comment: Can you include some of your CSS? Specifically interested in how you set sizes (which units you use)

Comment: @Konrad What do you mean with desktop mode?

Comment: @HenryWoody In this minimal example I dont have any css. Ive tried alot of code, but could not solve it. so in this example the css.code is not used.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/13514529?hl=en

Comment: @Konrad yeah okay. But I can not count my users having desktop mode on their phone. It should look good regardless.

Comment: If an user decides to turn on desktop mode it should look like on desktop